# Changing for loop to while loop for non-range for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
for item in lst[0:]:
    temp1 = int(item[1])
    temp2 = int(item[2])
```

Here is a block of code representing the item for each element in the list.
How would I change it so it searches through each item in the list but using a while loop?

Comment: This is perfectly fine as a `for` loop. Why mess with that? And what have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you have:

```
for item in lst:
    temp1 = int(item[1])
    temp2 = int(item[2])
```

If you wanted to use list indexes instead of the list items themselves, you could instead do this:

```
for idx in range(len(lst)):
    temp1 = int(lst[idx][1])
    temp2 = int(lst[idx][2])
```

where `range()` essentially returns a list `[1, 2, 3, ...]` that gets iterated through (the actual way it works is more complicated, but you get the idea). Making a `while` loop is more or less the same, except that you have to do the iteration yourself using arithmetic:

```
idx = 0
end = len(lst)
while idx < end:
    temp1 = int(lst[idx][1])
    temp2 = int(lst[idx][2])
    idx += 1
```